# Signed ghostscript postscript print driver

Tags: windows, printing, driver, ghostscript, postscript

I am using the Windows postscript print driver that is shipped with ghostscript (`lib/ghostpdf.inf`) to generate postscript files from print jobs.

However the postscript driver is not digitally signed, so Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 won't allow installing it without booting into the "allow unsigned drivers"-mode.

**Do you know if there is any signed version out there to be used with the latest Windows versions?**

If thats not the case, I am fine compiling and signing it myself, however I was not able to find the source code for the postscript print driver within the git repo available at http://git.ghostscript.com/ghostpdl.git.
May I've just overseen it since I am not familiar with building drivers.

**Can one give me a hint where I can find the postscript driver files to compile it myself?**

**EDIT:** How does the .INF file tell windows where the driver binaries are located? I've looked into the "ClassGUID" however its the same for all drivers and the registry entry says something about `C:\Windows\System32\ntprint.dll`. I don't think this is important for the problem, is it?

Comment: This question appears to be moot as the newest Ghostscript installer includes signed drivers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To sign "the ghostscript driver" you just have to sign the INF-file that comes with Ghostscript.

There's an [article on technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd919238%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) describing the steps required to do so.

The steps are:

1) Create/acquire a certificate
2) Ensure that your computer trusts the certificate (place it in your cert store if required)
3) Download and install the [Windows Driver Kit (WDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg454513.aspx)
4) Change the `CatalogFile=oemprint.cat` in the INF file to `ghostpdf.cat`
5) Change the `DriverVer=01/02/2007,1.0.0.1` to `DriverVer=01/01/2013,1.0.0.1` (maybe you need some other date, you'll see that in the next step)
6) Use the `Inf2Cat` tool to create a cat file (was at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86` for me):

**NOTE**
Use cmd.exe not powershell, as powershell gives `Parameter format not correct.` error all the time

Command:

```
inf2cat.exe /driver:c:\path\to\folder\whereCatFileIsIn /os:7_X86,7_X64,8_X86,8_X64[,other OS you'd like to support]
```

7) Sign the cat file using the `signtool` (Same directory as the `Inf2Cat` tool)

Command:

```
SignTool.exe sign /f "C:Path\to\my.pfx" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll "C:\Path\To\ghostpdf.cat"
```

(See the [signtool docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more informations about the available paramters)

Answer (score 0):

.inf files are not drivers, they are just text files with some installer information. There is no signed version of this, nor do you need it, you can use the output of any PostScript driver with Ghostscript.

You can't compile a .inf file, because there is nothing to compile, I have no idea how you go about signing such a thing in the latest versions of Windows, but if you want to give it a try you can open the .inf file with a text editor.

Comment: I already tried using the `HP Color Laserjet 4700 PS Class Driver` but this one completly destroys the unicode mappings, when selecting text in the resulting PDF, I only get "rects" (instead of the text I expect)

Comment: The printer driver is built into Windows itself, the installer doesn't need to tell Windows where to find the PostScript pritner driver, Windows knows where the drivers are. There is no specific Ghostscript printer driver, just a PPD (PostScript Printer Description) file, which is *also* a text file. You can easily (using the Win32 API) install a PostScript printer armed with nothing more than a PPD.

Comment: Easily installing a PostScript driver using Win32 API sounds great! Can you tell me which Win32 function I would have to use? There's nothing like "AddDriver" or something in the [Win32 Spooler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162861%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If the print driver is build into windows itself, why do I get those unsigned-printer-driver-warning when selection the ghostscript INF-file? If its just that PPD file, would that one need to be signed?

Comment: I believe you want AddPrinter, not AddDriver, though its been some time since I wrote any of this stuff. As for the warnings, I have no control or insight into what MS reports.

Comment: [AddPrinter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) requires a [PRINTER_INFO_2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which requires `pDriverName` which must be an installed driver. If I want a driver like the one I get when I select the `ghostpdf.inf`, what would the driver name be? If I just need a driver name, what are the INF files for? I guess I first have to "register" the driver using the INF (which points to the PPD) and assign a name, which I then can use with the AddPrinter Win32 function.

Comment: I think I have to [sign the INF file itself](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd919238%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#bkmk_signstep4). I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: The installed driver will be pscript5.dll (for versions of Windows prior to 8) I have no idea what Windows 8 uses, its a totally different printing scheme. The .inf file associates the PPD file with the particular instance of the printer driver (the PPD describes the specific device to the generic driver). It may do other stuff, I don't know offhand

Answer (score 0):

Q: *Do you know if there is any signed version out there to be used with the latest Windows versions?*

*** Workaround ***
A: For my Postscript driver issue I re-used the already signed driver from freeware PDF generator PDFil Writer.
https://www.pdfill.com/freewriter.html

In my case, I am a Sybase Powerbuilder developer, and my application depends on the Ghostscript Postscript driver.

I hope this helps.